# Wordpress custom mod_rewrite - Not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Evening all,

I feel like I have been banging my head against a brick wall with this one for a while I now turn to you for help.

I have a Wordpress powered website that I have created some custom page templates on that use URL parameters in order to make them working.

Currently I have the pages working fine with the urls: mydomain.com/clubs/betting/?c=arsenal

What I am attempting to do is make this look prettier so it appears as: mydomain.com/clubs/betting/arsenal/

I thought this would be a 10 minute job but 1 and a half hours later I am still no further. My mod_rewrite looks like this:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^clubs/betting/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ clubs/betting/?c=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: WordPress does a ton of rewrite work in the actual PHP code.  You will not get the desired result by modifying your htaccess file.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the desired result? Via PHP maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rewrite api to call your php file rather than creating a page template. This would be the cleanest way really.

```
add_action('init', 'anew_rewrite_rule');
function anew_rewrite_rule(){
   //note matching betting/something 
   add_rewrite_rule('^betting\\/[a-z]','index.php?is_betting_page=1','top');  
}

add_action('query_vars','controller_set_query_var');
function controller_set_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'is_betting_page'); // ref url redirected to in add rewrite rule

    return $vars;
}


//we'll call it a template but point to your controller
add_filter('template_include', 'include_controller');
function include_controller($template){


    // see above 2 functions..
    if(get_query_var('is_betting_page')){
        //path to your template file -- update this!
        $new_template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/yourtemplatefile.php';
        if(file_exists($new_template)){
            $template = $new_template;
        } 
    }    

    return $template;    

}
```

Note: you need to go to settings after inserting this code and save permalinks, this flushes the rewrite rules.

This way wordpress will not attempt to resolve the url using its own rewrite mechanism...

You can grab the uri using the $_SERVER variables.

Of course if you are early enough in your project, you could create a custom post type called betting and set that as the base url, then arsenal would be a custom post type etc. You could then use get title to run whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a test later when I get home! - Think I understand most of it... The only bit that looks confusing is the 'is_betting_page' section.. What is that referencing?

Comment: the simple explanation its a query variable is_betting_page=1 will be passed in the internal uri (the visible uri will remain the same, its not redirected from the input uri if it is resolved) and the following function adds a argument to resolve the query var we have added. Wp routes everything through the index.php and the query vars determine the post / action to take. The 3rd reference is simply to pick up the query var again (ea function is seperate) and serve the php file you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David for pointing my in the right direction for this... I finally managed to work this out using the Wordpress Rewrite API.

In the end I used the following code in my functions.php file:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule(){
   //note matching betting/something 
   add_rewrite_rule('^clubs/betting/([^/]+)/?','index.php?page_id=160&club_name=$matches[1]','top');  
  add_rewrite_tag('%club_name%','([^/]*)');
}

 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

This allowed me to handle the url rewrite and still pass in the url parameter to my page so I could show the correct content on it.

I was then able to access the parameter in my page template using:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['club_name'];
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... Thought I would post up the code I ended up using in case anyone else is trying to do this.